# getappdata returning empty matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a piece of code in which I use `setappdata` and then later on I call the data using `getappdata` which returns an empty matirx even though it is not empty. A segment of my simplified code is below:

```
function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

C=str2double(get(hObject,'String'))
setappdata(hObject,'H',C)

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

N=getappdata(hObject,'H')
```

When I run the code I enter a value into the `editbox` then push the `pushbutton`, I get the following output

```
C =

     5


N =

     []
```

I would like the following output

```
C =

     5


N =

     5
```

I should explain that I am using `getappdata` and `setappdata` as I want to pass data between different GUI's, and I am having the empty matrix problem when doing this. So this is a very simplified problem of my final goal. I have also read a lot of different articles and the information on this problem and commands, including the mathworks site but I am pretty lost with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's explain what's going on.

Within `edit1_Callback`, you're applying `setappdata` to `hObject`. At this point `hObject` refers to `edit1`, the editbox, and you've set its application data value `H` to 5.

Then you're calling `getappdata` within `pushbutton1_Callback`. At this point `hObject` refers to `pushbutton1`, and you're getting its application data value `H`, which has never been set, so you get `[]`.

A previous answer has suggested that you instead use `setappdata` and `getappdata` on the root object 0. This would work, but it's basically the same as using a global variable, which is BAD.

Instead, I would suggest that you most likely want to just ensure that you're setting and getting the application data on the correct thing. Within `edit1_Callback`, try:

```
setappdata(handles.edit1,'H',C)
```

and within `pushbutton1_Callback`, try:

```
N=getappdata(handles.edit1, 'H')
```

I think that should work (it assumes that the editbox is actually called `edit1`, which I think is likely given your GUIDE-generated code, but change that if you've called it something else).

Comment: I suppose the beauty about using `0` was that all my variables could be accessed from one handle by using different names. But I chose not to use global variables for a reason so I think this answer that Sam has given is more appropriate for me. Thanks

Comment: You can get a sort of halfway approach if you like, without truly global variables, by storing everything in the `appdata` of the main figure of your GUI (if you have multiple windows, choose one that will always exist for the life time of the application). Then the data will be 'global to the GUI', but not actually global. If you find it a hassle to be passing around a handle to the GUI figure. assign something unique to its `Tag` property and then retrieve its handle wherever you like with `h=findobj('Tag','something')`.

Comment: I actually have a problem when using `handles.edit1` instead of `0` when trying to pass the data between GUI's when using `0` it worked fine but when using `handles.edit1` or `handles.*appropiateTag*`i get `Reference to non-existent` error

Comment: That's right. `handles` is variable that GUIDE creates for each GUI, and the handles of one GUI won't be present in the `handles` variable for the other GUI. Also, it doesn't contain fields named by Tag, it contains fields with the component names, so `handles.*Tag*` won't work. To work across multiple GUIs, you'll need to either pass any necessary handles between them explicitly, or set the `Tag` property of everything and use `findobj` as I suggested. (General advice: making multi-window GUIs with GUIDE is a painful experience).

Answer (score 2):

You may use `0` instead of `hObject`. It will read/write your variable H in root workspace.

```
setappdata(0,'H',C);
getappdata(0,'H');
```

Comment: This will work, but is basically the same as using a global variable, which is a bad idea in general. See my answer below for an alternative suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information @SamRoberts, your advice has been taken on bored and is much appreciated. But thanks again Magla this solution does work.