# Defining MATLAB GUI default values before object creation

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, appdata

I like to define variables (such as `Appdata`) before GUI objects are created. I couldn't immediatly find the following questions online:

- General question 1) What determines the order of execution of different object creation functions `_CreateFcn` or are they all run parallel?
- General question 2) The `OpeningFcn` runs **after** object creation. Is there a function that runs **before** object creation?
- Specific question: My goal is to remember the property values of a GUI. So after properties have been changed (e.g by callbacks) and the GUI is closed, it should remember these properties after starting the GUI again. If it is the first time the GUI is started, or if all appdata has been reset, it should use the default values.

At the moment (it works) I define these property values for each individual `_createFcn` (see example code), but for 20+ create functions it is very cumbersome. Is it possible to define my default appdata before object creation such that I don't need so many if loops? (see example code 2)

example code 1 (current situation):

```
% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function checkbox_res_mot_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to checkbox_res_mot (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called
if isappdata(0,'Simulation')     %check if appdata exists
  simulation = getappdata(0,'Simulation');
  if  any(strcmp(fieldnames(simulation),'residual_motions'))     %check if variable exists
      set(hObject,'Value',simulation.residual_motions);     % stored value
  else
      set(hObject,'Value',0);    % default value
  end
else
  set(hObject,'Value',0);    % default value
end
simulation.residual_motions = get(hObject,'Value');      % create appdata
setappdata(0,'Simulation',simulation)
```

example code 2 (proposal):

```
%Executs before object creation
function default_values
if ~isappdata(0,'Simulation')
simulation.residual_motions = 0          % default values all in same function (only 1 variable shown as example)
setappdata(0,'Simulation',simulation)    % create appdata

%% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function checkbox_res_mot_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to checkbox_res_mot (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called
simulation = getappdata(0,'Simulation');        % no need to check appdata as it has already been created
set(hObject,'Value',simulation.residual_motions);    % residual_motions has been created in 'default value' code or is saved from last GUI execution
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, you can either 1) save the session data into a `.mat` file before the GUI closes and loads it the next time your start the GUI, or 2) output the session data to workspace before GUI closes, and pass it to GUI function as an argument the next time you start the GUI. Here's a code snippet that implements both options for a very simple GUI named `test` that is created through GUIDE and has a single edit text box in it.

```
function test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
if ~isempty(varargin)
    set(handles.edit1, 'String', varargin{1})
elseif exist('sessiondata.mat','file')
    temp_data = load('sessiondata.mat','output');
    set(handles.edit1, 'String', temp_data.output) 
end
guidata(hObject, handles);
uiwait(handles.figure1);

function varargout = test_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
output = get(handles.edit1, 'String');
varargout{1} = output;
save('sessiondata.mat', 'output')
delete(handles.figure1);

function figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
uiresume(hObject);
```

Normally when you click on the X button to close the GUI, a default `CloseRequestFcn` is called. The default version does only one thing: killing the GUI. In the case above, we enable the `uiwait` in the `OpeningFcn` to make the program wait for user response ( which is closing the GUI in this case). Then in `CloseRequestFcn`, `uiresume` directs the GUI to the `OutputFcn`, which then pass data to `varargout` and kills the GUI.

You can use the GUI in two ways, either simply run it without argument, or

```
output = test(input)
```

Without argument, whatever you typed in the edit text box will be stored in the `sessiondata.mat` and loaded the next time you start the GUI. If you supply argument to the function, it will use this argument to change the text in the edit text box. The output argument will be whatever text is left in the edit text box before you close the GUI.

Answer for general question 1: This is mostly my guess. I think it's determined by the order in which you create the objects if you're using GUIDE. This information is stored in `.fig` file. I'm making this guess because GUIDE apparently is tracking object creation and the information is not stored in the `.m` file.

Answer for general question 2: `CreateFcn` is part of the `gui_mainfcn`, which is supposedly the first function executed during GUI creation. While `OpeningFcn` runs after object creation, it is executed before the GUI is available for user interaction so you can set up your GUI in the `OpeningFcn`. You can also try to change the `CreateFcn` for each object, but you'll have to place codes in every `CreateFcn`.  So, I think `OpeningFcn` will be a better place for you to setup your GUI.

Comment: Sorry for my late reponse but thanks for your feedback!
You mentioned that I can use .mat' files or workspace to store my GUI session. However, this was not the problem as I stored everything in `appdata(0)`.

The reason I wanted to load this session **before** object creation is because each object `CreateFcn` uses this information. 

Your 2 answers on the general questions made me realise it will be more reliable to remove all code from `CreateFcn` and define everything during the `OpeningFcn`. I need to figure out how to work  with the `handles` first, then I will update my work in here!

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `appdata` will be lost once your GUI is closed. It's meant for sharing data between callbacks when GUI is alive. If you want information generated during the GUI execution, you'll need permanent means, such as saving data in a file or variable in the workspace.

Comment: In my case the `appdata` is stored as long as Matlab itself is open. So everytime Matlab is started at the beginning of the day it can only use default values, and that is fine by me. Maybe I am not using `appdata` as it is 'supposed' to be used. It just seems so convient to store all my (global) variables in it.

Comment: I suppose you declare `appadata` as a global variable as well? The `appdata` I refer to is the data stored along with the `handles` structure using the `setappdata` method. If you store these info as global variable, then of course it would persistent beyond the GUI session because it's living in a global space, rather than the GUI work space, which is created and destroyed each time you run it. I have to remind you, using global variable for this purpose is strongly discouraged because you can easily override builtin function without even noticing it.

Comment: I did a little research and it turned out that `appdata(0)` is the root workspace of Matlab and therefore indeed a global variable. Source: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330949/getappdata-returning-empty-matrix-matlab'. I know global variables are generally a bad idea, but I do not immediatly see the issue for `appdata(0)`. At the start of Matlab its actually empty, thus not used by integrated matlab codes?

Comment: hm. I actually don't know about `setappdata(0, m)`. Thanks for sharing this. Still, if there's other solution, for example, the two I proposed in my answer, avoid using global variable. It's difficult to track down. I didn't realize this when I first learn MATLAB. It gradually became clear to me.